# How can I get Selenium not to timeout when I have "paused" it via STDIN?

Tags: php, selenium, timeout

I started up Selenium with [this webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) in Chrome. After using `->get()` to go to a website I did the following

```
$term = 'o';
while($term != 'x')
{   
    echo "\nCommand: ";
    $term = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    echo "\nInputted Command = '".$term."'";
}
```

Now if I let it sit not putting anything in, the session will timeout

[image: CMD 1]

As you can see from the top, I used the command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java" -jar -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=86400 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

Since `Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout` is in seconds, the session shouldn't timeout for 1000 days. But even if I took off 3 0's, so that it's only 1 day as shown bellow:

[image: CMD 2]

In both cases since the session times out it closes the Chrome window that was opened for Selenium. If I send any command to Selenium like `->get()` throws an exception.

It still times out in about 30 minutes. Now I figure if I can't get that `Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout` to work properly (if it isn't working already) I need to put in something that can run in the background on a timer to keep Selenium active when it idles for like 10 minutes which I can trigger before I reach my `$term = trim(fgets(STDIN));` but I'm not sure what counts to Selenium to keep it active (because I din't think an injected javascript timer counts).

I know it's kinda against the point of using Selenium to be coding up something to avoid long periods of idleness, but so it's using to download ~6,000 images automatically off a website or create draft posts for wordpress based off content from `.txt` files.

Is there any way I can get Selenium not to timeout when I have "paused" it via STDIN?

Comment: which browser version are you using  ? not sure but try with upgrade your selenium webdriver jar.

Comment: @prakashtank sorry for the wait. i'm using Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) and i have gotten the latest version of Selenium Server but it still does the exact same thing. after the `->get()` in ~30 minutes the session times out

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/selenium-session-timeout  I guess it can be helpful !

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount nope because from what i understand of the question it's asking about a timeout caused during script execution. a wait before the `STDIN` for me would be pointless because it's not predictable how long i might be unable to make an input to continue the script and Selenium can't be corrupting cookies or sessions after 30 minutes of running because i've had a script run for 12 hours downloading images without a timeout.